# To get exaception when the csv files headers are not identical or same

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here I am trying to load multiple csv files and return exception if I wrongly entered csv with different column headers.

But I did first part loading all csv files but exception part I got stuck on can any one help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


# use glob to get all the csv files
# in the folder
path = os.getcwd()#my folder path with csv files
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))


# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
    
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    
    # print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
    
    # print the content
    print('Content:')
    display(df)
    print()
```

Here I am trying to get exception when csv file is wrongly entered for example if I want to load 10 csv files from /data folder but 9 have column headers as id,name,address and the 10th one has id,road,street,lane ,the code should throw error in this scenario that csv files are not identical else it will concat and give all in one csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you properly know or if you can define which columns are appropriate then you can do the following:

```
appropriate_columns = ['id', 'name', 'address']
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    # do a set difference of column names and check if length is 0
    if len(set(df.columns) - set(appropriate_columns)) != 0:
        print("Inappropriate Columns exist in file")
    else:
        print('Location:', f)
        print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
        print('Content:')
        display(df)
```

Comment: No,we dont know column names here because I want to implement on large datasets.